# How to write output file of ruby code into specific directory/location?

Tags: ruby

I have ruby code which will create output file, currently file is creating at location from where my script is running.
I have to write output file to different location so i am specifying explicit path into code. but it's not able to create file. my code looks like :

```
fname = "C:\repo\cookbooks\abc\recipes\add.rb"
somefile = File.open(fname,"w")  
somefile.puts "end"
somefile.close
```

If i specify

```
fname = "add.rb"
```

it's working but i want to create it at different location as i mentioned above code in C:\ drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `\` in strings are special characters so you should use `\\` (double backslashes) to get a single backslash. But there is a better way, you don't need to deal with backslashes at all:

```
fname = File.join("C:", "repo", "cookbooks", "abc", "recipes", "add.rb")
```

Comment: As far as I know you can also use `/` instead and it'll be converted automatically, or you can use single quotes to avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: Yep, there are other ways :)

Comment: In particular, `\r` is a *CARRIAGE RETURN*.